# VLookup without an exact match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider I have following values in Workbook1 (disregard the quotes):

```
Cell A1 - "C123 - Description"
Cell B1 - "Input"
Cell C1 - "Output"
Cell D1 - "Change"
```

Now, Workbook2 has

```
Cell A1 - "C123"
```

Question:

How do I do a vlookup in Workbook2 for "C123" from Workbook1 since "C123" is not "C123 - Description" i.e. both the A1 values are not exact?

Please let me know if I need to be more clear with my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wild cards:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1 & " *",Sheet2!A:D,4,FALSE)
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Hey..the above solution does a vlookup with the first instance of C123..even if the cell contents are C1234...I want it to only consider the characters before a space i.e. only if it is C123 - XXX..Could you maybe advise on how to improve the above formula? I dont want it to do a vlookup with C1234 just because "C1234" is before "C123 - Description" in a column.